# Getting the type of the sensors on an Android device (prior to API level 20)

Tags: java, android-sensors

I want to know what sensors a given Android device has. Before API level 20, sensor.getTypeString() was not available. I can however obtain the integer type, using sensor.getType().

I can make a list of types ("TYPE_ACCELEROMETER", "TYPE_AMBIENT", ...), but somehow I need to determine the value of Sensor.XXX for each type.

I had imagined that an expression like Sensor[sensorType] (where sensorType is a string such as "TYPE_ACCELEROMETER") would work, but Java doesn't agree with me on this. It complains that Sensor is not a variable.

I know I could use a `switch` statement or a  series of `if` statements (pseudocode):

```
int type = sensor.getType();
if (type == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
  return "TYPE_ACCELEROMETER";
} else if (type == TYPE_AMBIENT) {
  return "TYPE_AMBIENT";
} else
  ...
}
```

Can you recommend a more elegant way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `public List<Sensor> getSensorList (int type)` in `SensorManager` class passing in `Sensor.TYPE_ALL` to get all available sensors in the device.